# Dependency Injection - Logging Best Practices for c# .net core libraries - While hiding sub library dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an entry point class (MotionDetectionSerializer) in a C# .net-core library that deserializes JSON into an immutable POCO class using *System.Text.Json* (see below).

Within the constructor I build the dependencies, registering custom Converters and associated loggers. This was mainly done for the purpose of hiding System.Text.Json dependencies from the library user.

However, I am not convinced this design is good practice and have read that dependency injection for loggers is easier for testing. I have read an [article](https://blog.rsuter.com/logging-with-ilogger-recommendations-and-best-practices/) that suggests not to use ILoggerFactory.

How are others provided loggers for their libraries in entry point classes and associated helpers, while hiding third party library dependencies in constructor?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using WebApp.Data.Serializers.Converters;
using WebApp.Data.Serializers.Converters.Visitors;

namespace WebApp.Data.Serializers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class to deserialize json into a MotionDetection object
    /// Deserialization is performed to class instance properties 
    /// using CamelCase property naming policy.
    /// </summary>
    public class MotionDetectionSerializer
    {
        private JsonSerializerOptions SerializationOptions { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Construct a serializer to deserialize json into a MotionDetection object's
        /// corresponding CamelCase properties.
        /// </summary>
        public MotionDetectionSerializer()
        {
            var logger = default(ILogger<MotionDetectionConverter>);
            var loggerInfo = default(ILogger<MotionInfoConverter>);
            var loggerVisitor = default(ILogger<JsonVisitor>);

            using (var logFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole()))
            {
                logger = logFactory.CreateLogger<MotionDetectionConverter>();
                loggerInfo = logFactory.CreateLogger<MotionInfoConverter>();
                loggerVisitor = logFactory.CreateLogger<JsonVisitor>();
            }

            JsonVisitor visitor = new JsonVisitor(loggerVisitor);

            SerializationOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase };
            SerializationOptions.Converters.Add(new MotionDetectionConverter(visitor, logger));
            SerializationOptions.Converters.Add(new MotionInfoConverter(visitor, loggerInfo));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads a json stream and deserializes into a MotionDetection object.
        /// The underlying stream is closed after the operation completes or an exception is thrown.
        /// The stream is read until completion.
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<MotionDetection> FromJSONAsync(Stream stream)
        {
            if (stream is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(@"Failed to deserialize from null stream");
            }

            MotionDetection obj = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<MotionDetection>(stream, SerializationOptions);

            return obj;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads a json stream and deserializes into a MotionDetection object.
        /// The underlying stream is closed after the operation completes or an exception is thrown.
        /// The stream is read until completion.
        /// </summary>
        public MotionDetection FromJSON(Stream stream)
        {
            if (stream is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(@"Failed to deserialize from null stream");
            }

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MotionDetection>(reader.ReadToEnd(), SerializationOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A question out of curiosity: why use `var logger = default(ILogger<MotionDetectionConverter>);` and not just `ILogger<MotionDetectionConverter> logger = null;` (or `ILogger<MotionDetectionConverter> logger = default;` in C# 7+)?

Comment: @John No reason could change when design stabilises....